# MIPS addi signed interger

Tags: mips, cpu-architecture

I'm trying to solve the following problem:

Register $4 contains the 32-bit IEEE 754 representation of  -31.5, what is the final result placed into $5 by the following instructions:

```
sll     $5,$4,1
srl     $5,$5,24
addi    $5,$5,-127
```

> ```
> $4 = 11000001 11111100 00000000 00000000
> after performing sll $5,$4,1
> $5 = 10000011 11111000 00000000 00000000
> after performing srl $5,$5,24
> $5   = 00000000 00000000 00000000 10000011
> -127 = 11111111 11111111 11111111 10000001
> ```

From my understanding addi will take 16 bits of the immediate in this case 11111111 10000001 and add it to the register $5 value. Will the final value be 11111111 00000100 or 00000000 00000100 after adding both values?

Comment: Do the arithmetic in decimal, and convert that result to binary.  (It will come out the same in this case as there is no overflow.)

Comment: I tried something like it. I know the value of register $5 before addi is 131, the final result in decimal should be 4.

Comment: If you want to understand the binary operation, look at how the carry-out from `1+1` at the top of the low byte propagates into / through the all-ones in the bits above it (where `$5` had zeros).